# Query subdocument in Monogo DB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have the following Mongo Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea0576c2671f799e1ad65db"),
    "model" : "Volkswagen",
    "make" : "Volkswagen",
    "year" : 1969,
    "mileage" : 15000.0,
    "vi_number" : "ba37d9b98fe940dba100fdf0330c30f0",
    "engine" : {
        "horsepower" : 400,
        "liters" : 5.0,
        "mpg" : 20.0,
        "serial_number" : "a9ff4120-ee34-4588-af1a-77f62457531f"
    },
    "service_history" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-04-22T12:10:55.622Z"),
            "description" : "Cleaning",
            "price" : 150.0,
            "customer_rating" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-04-22T12:14:53.439Z"),
            "description" : "Flat tire",
            "price" : 100.0,
            "customer_rating" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2020-04-22T12:30:54.071Z"),
            "description" : "Waxing",
            "price" : 77.0,
            "customer_rating" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

I created the following query in Python and it returns all subdocuments:

```
cars = Car.objects().filter(service_history__customer_rating__lte=2)
```

When I run the following query directly in Mongo:

```
db.getCollection('cars').find({'service_history.customer_rating': {$lte: 2}})
```

It returns again all the subdocuments instead of just one.

I checked the documentation and everything seems correct.

Comment: You want to filter the data within the `service_history` field?

Comment: @prasad_ yes, I want to return the parent document with all its service_histories that qualifies the customer rating...

Comment: You have to use an aggregation query to get the `service_history` array filtered on a condition. The `$project` (or `$addFields`)  stage can use a [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) array operator to filter array elements based upon a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look at the following query. Hope this will help you. You need to use MongoDB Aggregations to find `$lte` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$service_history"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": ObjectId("5ea0576c2671f799e1ad65db")
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $lte: [
          "$service_history.customer_rating",
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This would be the sample data you would be getting if you would use the above query.

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5ea0576c2671f799e1ad65db"),
    "engine": {
      "horsepower": 400,
      "liters": 5,
      "mpg": 20,
      "serial_number": "a9ff4120-ee34-4588-af1a-77f62457531f"
    },
    "make": "Volkswagen",
    "mileage": 15000,
    "model": "Volkswagen",
    "service_history": {
      "customer_rating": 2,
      "date": ISODate("2020-04-22T12:14:53.439Z"),
      "description": "Flat tire",
      "price": 100
    },
    "vi_number": "ba37d9b98fe940dba100fdf0330c30f0",
    "year": 1969
  }
]
```

**Updated query**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$service_history"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $lte: [
          "$service_history.customer_rating",
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[You can refer to this code.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pVTTi31IqqX)

Comment: But what if I do not know the ID of the parent?

Comment: Just remove the 1st match operator. Updated the example. Refer to that code

Answer (score 3):

```
db.getCollection('cars').find({'service_history.customer_rating': {$lte: 2}})
```

edit:

What happens here is it checks for the customer_rating and since it finds a match it returns the  Document. The whole thing that is returned is the document.

PS: Sorry for the confusion earlier.

Comment: Hey, why is that? I am checking the documentation and it says that I can select the items that are less or equals than 2. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/

Comment: How would you refactor it to return the items with a rating less or equals than 5?